# How can I run command in a folder without changing my current directory to it?

Tags: bash, command-line, scripts

may be it seems strange for you, but I want to run command in a specific folder without changing the current folder in the shell. Example - this is what I usually do:

```
~$ cd .folder
~/.folder$ command --key
~/.folder$ cd ..
~$ another_command --key
```

Though I want something like this:

```
~$ .folder command --key
~$ another_command --key
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can't you do `~/.folder/command --key` ? Does the `command` require your current directory to be `~/.folder` ?

Comment: @glennjackman Commands such as `git pull` require to change folder, so the question is useful. )

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you want to avoid the second `cd` you can use

```
(cd .folder && command --key)
another_command --key
```

Comment: Very quick answer! I even can't to accept it because system doesn't allow me))

Comment: magic parenthesis! how does that work? +1

Comment: The commands within the parenthesis are run in a new shell process so changing the directory, setting environment variables etc. inside the parenthesis do not affect the parent shell that runs the other commands.

Comment: So sad that `bash` can't do this with pre-setting env variable like this: `PWD=/some/path command`. This seems more organic while sub-shell looks like hack

Answer (score 12):

Without `cd`... Not even once. I found two ways:

```bsh
# Save where you are and cd to other dir
pushd .folder
command --key
# Get back where you were at the beginning.
popd
another_command --key
```

and second:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name ".folder" -execdir command --key \;
another_command --key
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a need to do this in a bash-free way, and was surprised there's no utility (similar to `env(1)` or `sudo(1)` which runs a command in a modified working directory. So, I wrote a simple C program that does it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char ENV_PATH[8192] = "PWD=";

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: in <dir> <cmd> [<args>...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(chdir(argv[1])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting working directory to \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    if(!getcwd(ENV_PATH + 4, 8192-4)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting the full path to the working directory \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        return 3;
    }

    if(putenv(ENV_PATH)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting the environment variable \"%s\"\n", ENV_PATH);
        return 4;
    }

    execvp(argv[2], argv+2);
}
```

The usage is like this:

```
$ in /path/to/directory command --key
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple bash function for running a command in specific directory:

```
# Run a command in specific directory
run_within_dir() {
    target_dir="$1"
    previous_dir=$(pwd)
    shift
    cd $target_dir && "$@"
    cd $previous_dir
}
```

Usage:

```
$ cd ~
$ run_within_dir /tmp ls -l  # change into `/tmp` dir before running `ls -al`
$ pwd  # still at home dir
```

Comment: You don't need to remember the previous dir if you run the function in a subshell: `run_within_dir() ( ... )` using parentheses instead of braces.